# Command "docpad run" is getting error: "module" is undefined

Tags: node.js, docpad

I've migrated my configurations from *docpad.coffee* to **docpad.js** (personal preference on using plain Javascript)

Since then, I'm not being able to execute the command

```
docpad run
```

And I'm keep getting this error:

[image: error]

I've validated my configurations against JSLint and made sure there's no syntax error.

I'm good to go with docpad.coffee, but it'd be great if someone could help me on fixing this

Comment: Strange. I've used `docpad.js` with success before. Can you put up a link to your repo, or an example repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sorry I've not put it up in any repo yet (there's nothing much to commit). Am just starting to play around. Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4664798)

Comment: I renamed `docpad.js` to `_docpad.js` and do a `module.exports = require("./_docpad")` in the `docpad.coffee`, and things worked. I'm using node.js version 0.8.18 though.

Comment: Please post the `docpad.js` file you used to produces the error.

Comment: For me `docpadConfig = require("./docpad.conf.js"); module.exports = docpadConfig` (in `docpad.coffee`) + `var docpadConfig = {}; module.exports = docpadConfig;` (in `docpad.conf.js`) did the trick as well. Looks like the node module system does not get properly initialized unless we include the file like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `docpad.cmd run` instead of `docpad run` to distinguish between the local docpad.js and the global npm-installed docpad.cmd.

Answer (score 2):

This is because windows recognises the ".js" extension as a javascript file and tries to run your docpad.js file when you issue the "docpad run" command. Windows script host is what is used by windows to run js files natively (so actually nothing to do with node or docpad itself). The reference to "module" in the error message is because that is the first line of the docpad.js file and the windows script host doesn't know what "module" is. You can just rename your docpad.js file to .coffee (I believe all javascript is valid coffee script) and then the windows message will disappear.

Edit: I've just went and tested this on the docpad skeleton which has a docpad.js file instead of docpad.coffee. Simply renaming it to docpad.coffee does indeed solve the problem. Renaming it back to .js then causes the 'Windows Script Host' error message to appear when the "docpad run" command is issued.